# Trying to write a class in C++ that only reads in the first column of data and skips to the next line

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector

This may be a very simplistic question, but I have not found any examples to guide me.  I am trying to write class in C++ that can read a text file where columns of data (float, char, int, etc...) are separated by spaces.  I would like the class to be able to ignore some columns and read in specified columns.  For now I am experimenting with one and two column formats and progressing from there.  A brief example of a test input file is listed below.

```
103.816   
43.984    
2214.5    
321.5     
615.8     
8.186     
37.6
```

My first attempt at writing a code to read in one column of data is trivial and looks like this.

```
void Read_Columnar_File::Read_File(const std::string& file_name)
{
    int i;
    std::ifstream inp(file_name,std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if(inp.is_open()) {     
    std::istream_iterator<float> start((inp)), end;
    std::vector<float> values(start,end);
    for(i=0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "Cannot Open " << file_name << std::endl;
    inp.close();
}
```

In my next attempt I am trying to read in only one column of a two column format like the input shown below.  The numbers are just made up for this example

```
103.816   34.18
43.984    21.564
2214.5    18.5
321.5     1.00
615.8     4.28
8.186     1.69
37.6      35.48
```

I modified the code format slightly to look like the example below.  I am using a brief but of pseudocode after the inp >> statement to illustrate that I am trying to get the code to skip to the next line after reading in the first column.  my question is "How do I get the code to just read the first column and then skip to the next line where again it just reads the first column of data and make it keep doing this until the end of file?"  And thank you in advance for any advice that you can give.

```
void Read_Columnar_File::Read_File(const std::string& file_name)
{
    int i;
    float input;
    std::vector<float> values;
   std::ifstream inp(file_name,std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
   if(inp.is_open()) {
       for(i=0; i < 7; i++) {
           inp >> input >> \\ - At this point I want the code to skip to the next
                           \\   line of the input file to only read the first column
                           \\   of data
           values.push_back(input);
       }
    for(i=0; i < 7; i++) std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;
    }
    else std::cout << "Cannot Open " << file_name << std::endl;

    inp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the member function `ignore()` to discard all the characters until the next line. I would also fix up your code to use a `for()` loop predicated on the success of the extraction so your code will work for any number of columns, not just 7:

```
for (float input; inp >> input; values.push_back(input))
{
    inp.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to read only part of a line, and skip the rest of that line, one easy starting point is to:

1. read the entire line into a string
2. put the whole string into an istringstream
3. Parse out the parts you care about
4. Repeat

As a rule, I generally find this easier to generalize than ones that alternate between reading and ignoring data as it's being read from the file.

Comment: This is also good because since you have the line you can save the data that you skip over, which for file streams are technically not guaranteed to be recoverable.

Comment: Thank you (both of you) for your answer to my question.  I was hoping that there might be an advance command in C++, like in fortran that lets me advance to the next line after a specific column  is read in, but that seems to not be the case.  However, your answer is still very helpful.  Forgive me for not up-rating your answer, but I am new to the site and do not have a high enough rating myself to up rate people.

Comment: When I tried to update both of you the website produced a message stating that I had to have a minimum rep of 15 to update someone.

Comment: @Jon: Apparently my recollection was wrong. Sorry 'bout that.